# How can I use YAML to configure multiple log files for Logback/Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, logback, dropwizard

I'm rewriting a small DropWizard application to run on SpringBoot.

My DW app has the following logging config which works:

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /var/log/paas/console.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/paas/console.log-%d.gz
      archivedFileCount: 7

  loggers:
    com.myorg:
      level: DEBUG
      appenders:
        - type: file
          currentLogFilename: /var/log/paas/paas.log
          archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/paas/paas.log-%d.gz
          archivedFileCount: 7
```

This config separates my application and console messages into two separate logs.

When I try using this same configuration with SpringBoot, it has no effect. I'm able to write everything to a single log with the following config, but I really need to have two separate logs:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    com.myorg: DEBUG
  file: /var/log/paas/paas.log
```

Is it not possible to do this with LogBack and YAML? Or is there an alternate syntax that will give me the same result I'm getting for my DropWizard app?

Comment: I have same need, Did you figure out how to get it?

Answer (score 7):

Spring Boot's YAML configuration of Logback only allows a single file appender. In order to configure Logback to use multiple file appenders you'll have to provide an explicit `logback.xml` or `logback-spring.xml`. If you remove the logging confoguraiotn from your `application.yaml` file and then add either a `logback.xml` or a `logback-spring.xml` to the root of your runtime classpath then Logback will be configured from that file.

Here's an example, using a `logback.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="INFO_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- deny all events with a level below INFO, that is TRACE and DEBUG -->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <file>/var/log/paas/console.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/paas/console.log-%d.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>...</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DEBUG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/paas/paas.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/paas/paas.log-%d.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>...</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```